# When I click the button data is not updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to get update working in my project ,where the user clicks on a link and they are brought to that page(I have that part working) where they can make changes .At the moment I have created and update function but nothing happens when user clicks on button .

This my home.blade.php where the user clicks on the link to bring them to another page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  />
    </head>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            {{--Friend request--}}
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                @if ($available_req_count > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                        <strong>Your have pending friend request
                            <a href="{{ url('friends/viewReq') }}" class="alert-link">Please check</a>
                        </strong>.
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home','files' =>true]) !!}
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Add a new status</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Write a new status</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="status-text" id="status-text"></textarea>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div id="image_upload">

                                    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">

                                    <i class="fa fa-image"></i> or <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>

                                </label>
                                    <input id="file-upload" name="status_image_upload" type="file"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9=">

                                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add status
                                </button>


                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

                @foreach($top_15_posts as $status)
                    {!!
                    view('layouts.app-internal.user-status-layout',[
                     'status' => $status,
                     'user' => \App\Eloquent\User::find($status->user_id),
                     'comments' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(),
                      'comment_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusComments::where('status_id',$status->id)->count(),
                      'like_count' => \App\Eloquent\StatusLikes::where('status_id',$status->id)->count()

                     ])
                     !!}
                @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

These are the links in the homepage
[image: These are the links in the homepage]

This edit.blade.php where the user is brought to from home page :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"  />

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Edit a status</div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group" action="{{url('edit')}}/{{$status->id}}" method="POST" role="form">
            <label>Write a new status</label>
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home','files' =>true]) !!}
            <textarea class="form-control" name="status-text" id="status-text" value="{{ $status->id }}"></textarea>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="image_upload">

                    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">

                        <i class="fa fa-image"></i> or <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>

                    </label>
                    <input id="file-upload" name="status_image_upload" type="file"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9=">

                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add status
                </button>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

This is the layout of the edit page
[image]

This is the controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Eloquent\Status;
use App\Friends;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Laracasts\Flash\Flash;
//use Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if (Input::has('like_status')) {
            $status = Input::get('like_status');

            $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

            $selectedStatus->likes()->create([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'status_id' => $status
            ]);
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }

        if (Input::has('post_comment')) {
            $status = Input::get('post_comment');
            $commentBox = Input::get('comment-text');
            $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

            $selectedStatus->comments()->create([

                'comment_text' => $commentBox,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'status_id' => $status
            ]);
            Flash::message('Your comment has been posted');
            return redirect(route('home'));

        }
        if (Input::has('status-text')) {
            $text = e(Input::get('status-text'));

            $rules = [
                'status-text' => 'required|string',


            ];

            $vaildator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if (Input::hasFile('status_image_upload')) {

                $file = Input::file('status_image_upload');
                $mime = $file->getMimeType();

                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');

                $imageName = str_random(8) . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                //$imageFull = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus->status_text = $text;
                $userStatus->image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus->type = 1;
                $userStatus->user_id = Auth::user()->id;


                if ($mime == "video/x-flv" || $mime == "video/mp4" || $mime == "application/x-mpegURL" || $mime == "video/MP2T" || $mime == "video/3gpp" || $mime == "video/quicktime" || $mime == "video/x-msvideo" || $mime == "video/x-ms-wmv") {//process upload}

                    $vaildator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                    if (!$vaildator->fails()) {
                        $image->move('status_videos', $imageName);
                        $userStatus->type = 2;
                        $userStatus->save();
                        Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                        return redirect(route('home'));
                    } else {
                        return back()->with('error', 'Validation failed:' . $vaildator->errors);
                    }
                } else {
                    $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
                    $vaildator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                    if (!$vaildator->fails()) {
                        $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                        $userStatus->type = 1;
                        $userStatus->save();
                        Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                        return redirect(route('home'));
                    } else {
                        return back()->with('error', 'Validation failed:' . $vaildator->errors);
                    }
                }


            } else {
            }
            if (!$vaildator->fails()) {
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus->status_text = $text;
                $userStatus->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus->save();
                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('home'));
            } else {
                return back()->with('error', 'Validation failed:' . $vaildator->errors);
            }


        }


        //Get top 15 post
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $all_friends = Friends::where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'status' => 1])
            ->orWhere(['user_id' => $user_id, 'status' => 1])
            ->get();

        $friends = [];
        foreach ($all_friends as $val) {
            array_push($friends, $val->user_id, $val->friend_id);
        }

        $unique_friends = array_unique($friends);

        if (!empty($unique_friends)) {
            $top_15_posts = Status::whereIn('user_id', $unique_friends)
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->take(15)
                ->get();
        } else {
            $top_15_posts = Status::where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->take(15)
                ->get();
        }

        //Get available friend request
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $available_req_count = Friends::where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'status' => 0])
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->count();

        return view('home', [
            'top_15_posts' => $top_15_posts,
            'available_req_count' => $available_req_count

        ]);


    }
    public function getDeleteStatus($status_id)
    {
        $status =Status::where('id',$status_id)->first();
//        if(Auth::id() != $status->user){
//            return redirect()->back();
//        }
        $status->delete();
        return redirect()->route('home')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!']);
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $status = Status::find($id);
        return view('edit',compact('status'));

    }

}
```

Comment: you question is not clear, please refer exact to where the problem it is

Comment: When I click on the button in edit.blade ,nothing happends but I want the data to update the new information

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on the button in edit.blade ,nothing happends

in your edit.blade.php and form that you defin there is no submit button

replace :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add status
            </button>
```

with button code in edit.blade.php

let me know if you have any errors

Comment: The data is still not change ,I think the issue is in the controller ...